# Is it possible to import a class defined in a .groovy script from a GroovyTestCase?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, junit

I have a groovy script defined, which includes an inner class

foo.groovy:

```
// does something

Bar {
  int foobar() {
    return 1
  }
}

// Does something else
```

Why I have the class defined in the script is a longer story, but it's necessary, unless I want to make a big redesign of the project structure (And the customer doesn't want to pay for this time)

Anyway, I have a GroovyTestCase, where I want to call this class from.

I want to do something like this:

```
class Test extends GroovyTestCase {
  void testSomething() {
    Bar bar = new Bar()
    assertTrue(1, bar.foobar())    
  }
}
```

Is it possible to reference a class defined in a groovy script? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

foo.groovy

```
println "foooo 01"

class Bar {
  int foobar() {
    return 1
  }
}

println "foooo 02"
```

Test.groovy (you can make it as a class)

```
def shell = new GroovyShell()
//parse script
def script = shell.parse(new File("/11/foo.groovy"))
//get class loader used for script parsing
def cl = shell.getClassLoader()
//get list of parsed/loaded classes
println cl.getLoadedClasses() //  [class Bar, class foo]

def bar = cl.loadClass('Bar').newInstance()
println bar.foobar() // 1
```

but beware! if your `foo.groovy` script loaded some other classes that you want to access in testcase, you have to do it through the same shell classloader, otherwise there could be strange errors like `could not assign String to String`...